# Java EE 6 WAR packaging for pure server application?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, war, cdi

I currently set up a Java EE project for a new business application using CDI. The application is a pure server application (using jms, webservices and such, but has no frontend).

Since we are using Java EE 6, I would like to use the new WAR packaging instead of the former EAR, which seems to be a simpler packaging mechanism to me and was recommended to use if one has no special modularization needs.

My problem in understanding is now, that I am still thinking of a WAR as a web application. How is the project layout in my case, do I still have for example a WEB-INF folder even though I don't have any frontend and there's no need to publish the application under a context? Or is there a better way to structure a pure server application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'new WAR' has the same layout as the 'old WAR', the only difference is that the EJB JAR(s) can now be placed inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of the WAR. In the 'old WAR' you could not place EJBs inside the WAR.

Comment: So, your're saying, I'm still having the structure 
`WEB-INF/classes,
WEB-INF/lib`
And what about the config files, is there for example web.xml necessary? Do I still have the application provided under a context even though I don't have any view?

Comment: yes, the WEB-INF/classes, WEB-INF/lib and WEB-INF/web.xml is there as usual. If your app exposes web services they will be mapped as servlets in WEB-INF/web.xml, from the WAR point of view your services are the views.